# WIX registry key entry fails using Auto Generated GUID

Tags: wix

Im using WIX 3.11.2 and when adding a registry key I get the following error:

***“The Component/@Guid attribute's value '*' is not valid for this component because it does not meet the criteria for having an automatically generated guid”***

I have created a ‘.wxs’ file which contains the following code that is failing:

```
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="myComponentGroup" Directory="TARGETDIR">
<Component Id="cmpRegUrlHandler" Guid="*">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myAppName\shell\open\command">
        <RegistryValue Value="C:\Program Files\\myCompanyName\myProductName" KeyPath="yes" />
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

I run it using candel.exe/light.exe. However, light.exe gives me the above error.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Guid="*"` for a component that has only a `RegistryKey`. You need to give it a real guid.